# How to comment multiple lines in env file

Tags: javascript, environment-variables, env-file

I wanted to know if there is any way to comment a block or multiple lines in `.env` file. I know that by using `#` we can comment a single line but I want to comment multiple lines at once. Currently I am using visual studio code in ubuntu and working on Vue(Javascript) project. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: From what I can see, its only the hash, but if you're using an editor such as visual code. You can select an entire are and use the hotkey to toggle the comment on the entire block at once.

Comment: Is this in any way related to your IDE? If not, please clarify your question

Comment: what library are you using for environment variables?

Answer (score 6):

Unfortunately there is no character sequences which could allow to comment lines in blocks in an `.env` file. As you said, the only way to comment is at *line level* with the `#` character.

A workaround would be looking for a shortcut in your IDE to employ *multi-line editing* (*e.g.* use `Shift + Alt + Arrow Keys` on Visual Studio Code in Linux).